# BTS7710G driver voltage drop

Tags: microcontroller, avr, driver, h-bridge

I'm trying to use a [BTS7710G](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/196/Infineon-BTS7710G-DS-v01_01-en-785254.pdf) as a h-bridge to swap voltage on load. this is from datasheet:
[image]

what i'm doing is turning on IH2 and IL1 pins at once . and another time turning on IH1 and IL2 to swap voltage on load  ( micro supply voltage is 5V).

but i see driver ic get to hot and output voltage without load is 5.5V and under load is 3 volt (supply voltage is 7V and load current is about 3A) . I'm wondering if i am doing something wrong

Comment: Are you doing a soft start with the motor?

Comment: There is no motor, I have connected three parallel TEC(peltier 12704) to the driver . each peltier consumes almost 1A current.

Answer (score 0):

When the IH2 and IL1 are turned on, IH1 and IL2 must be turned off. And vice versa. It is also desirable to use a protective interval when the switch is performed. During which IH1, IH2, IL1 and IL2 signals are off.

Comment: Yes , at first I turn off all four ports , then turn on desired two ports

Comment: Is it possible that micro ATMEGA8 ports can not directly fully drive gates? (In datasheet All 4 driver gates are directly connected to micro )

Comment: @alex Please measure the voltages on all four inputs and the current consumption of the driver without load when first in one condition of the bridge and then in the second. There may be an error in the configuration of the IO ports of the microcontroller.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced driver with another one the same and problem solved!now I have output voltage the same as input when no load and only one voltage drop with load.  I don't know why.it seems the first one gates didn't drive completely.